# Read coordinates from mouse click in mpld3

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon, interactive, onmouseclick

I generated a figure using mpld3 and linked it to plugins.MousePosition() to display the coordinates, as below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins, utils

x,y = np.random.rand(2,10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y,s=10,c='orange')

plugins.connect(fig, plugins.MousePosition())
mpld3.show()
```

The mouse position is reported in the lower right hand corner, which means the x,y coordinates can be read somehow. Is there a way to use the coordinate information to draw a polygon based on mouse click(s) and double click?

Answer (score 2):

This would be possible, but you'd essentially have to create a simple drawing program in d3/javascript, and then create a plugin that includes the javascript implementation.

I found a forum thread that might be of interest on this subject: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/zRgsx65hpWg/ivR0xwMPQt8J

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp. I circumvented the problem by first placing a polygon in the graph (implemented with a modified version of LinkedDragPlugin) and letting the user drag and move the vertices around. This is not the same as creating and destroying a polygon but for what I wanted to do, i.e. creating a gate for generating a histogram on the followup POST request, it worked ok.