# Is there a way to see the coordinates of a matplotlib scatterplot graph when doing a mouse over in HTML

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, scatter-plot, mplcursors

My first issue was to create check the coordinates of the points in scatterplot matplotlib with a mouse over, that part has been done with the code:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

....
....

df.plot.scatter(x='column1', y='column2')
mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
```

then i put the image in html code using this code:

```
plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')

page_title_text = 'My report'
title_text = 'title'
text = 'Hello, welcome to your report'

html = f'''
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>{page_title_text}</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>{title_text}</h1>
            <p>{text}</p>
            <img src='C:\\Users\\foo.png' width="700">
        </body>
    </html>
    '''
with open('C:\\Users\\html_report.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

That last part allowed me to load the image in a standalone html page but
obviously the mouse over won't work in this case since I'm loading a static image to the html, but is there any way at all to do this without a continuous connection to python, as in have a stand alone html that would allow to see the coordinates of scatterplot dots when having a mouse over?

**EDIT**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3

.
.
.

f= plt.gcf()
print(mpld3.fig_to_html(f))
```

then i wrote down the print to a file and saved as .html, as described in my comment i was able to see my plot in html but not the coordinates when doing a mouse over the dots.

Comment: you should use `matplotlib` to generate HTML with JavaScript code - not image `.png`

Comment: see module [mpld3](https://mpld3.github.io/quickstart.html) - it generates matplotlib plot as HTML with JavaScript code which uses library `D3.js`

Comment: @furas thank you for the suggestion, I did that and was able to save it as html but i still cannot see the values of coordinates in html when doing a mouse over, please find my edit in the question.

Comment: it may need to add some JavaScript code for this. Code in question [Read coordinates from mouse click in mpld3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069654/read-coordinates-from-mouse-click-in-mpld3) use some `plugin` - `MousePosition()`

Comment: @furas I did add that plugin and now it's even better than before as i can do a mouse over the canvas and get an approximate value, but it's a bit annoying to try to align the mouse over the exact center of the dot as no popup will be shown is there a way to adjust it where i'd get exact x,y values with mouse over especially that i read the html and the X,Y parameters are basically provided there

Comment: I don't know but maybe there is other plugin for this. Eventually you may get source code for `MousePosition()` and you can try to create own version - it would have to if there is data in small distanct and display information only for this data

Comment: I found example which use plugin to display label when mouse touch point (hover point) https://mpld3.github.io/examples/scatter_tooltip.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Matplotlib` generates static HTML but there is module [mpld3](https://mpld3.github.io/quickstart.html) which use `Matplotlib` with JavaScript module `D3.js` to create interactive plot in HTML.

It has also plugins to add some functions. i.e.

- `MousePosition` to show current mouse positon
- `PointLabelTooltip` to display tooltip (one line in plain text) when you touch/hover point
- `PointLabelTooltip` to display tooltip (HTML) when you touch/hover point.
  This allow to use `<br>` to put items in many lines.
  It can also use `CSS` to set colors, margins, padding, etc.

You can find more plugins with source code on GitHub in [plugins.py](https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/blob/master/mpld3/plugins.py)

You may use this to create own plugin but this need to know JavaScript.

---

Minimal working example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3

np.random.seed(0)

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, s=20, c='orange')
labels = [f'x: {a}<br>y: {b}' for a, b in zip(x, y)]

position = mpld3.plugins.MousePosition()
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, position)

#tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(scatter, labels=labels)
tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointHTMLTooltip(scatter, labels=labels, 
                                         hoffset=20, voffset=20, 
                                         css='.mpld3-tooltip{background-color: #cbc; padding: 15px}')
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)

#mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, position, tooltip)

mpld3.show()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Code for two plots.

The only problem: both plots has the same class `.mpld3-tooltip` in HTML so `css=...` set the same color for both plots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3

np.random.seed(0)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)  # `ax1, ax2` has to be with `( )`

#fig, all_ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
#ax1, ax2 = all_ax

# ---

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 10)
scatter1 = ax1.scatter(x, y, s=20, c='orange')
labels1 = [f'x: {a}<br>y: {b}' for a, b in zip(x, y)]

tooltip1 = mpld3.plugins.PointHTMLTooltip(scatter1, labels=labels1, 
                                         hoffset=20, voffset=20, 
                                         css='.mpld3-tooltip{background-color: #cbc; padding: 15px}')
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip1)

# ---

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 10)
scatter2 = ax2.scatter(x, y, s=50, c='blue')
labels2 = [f'x: {a}<br>y: {b}' for a, b in zip(x, y)]

tooltip2 = mpld3.plugins.PointHTMLTooltip(scatter2, labels=labels2, 
                                         hoffset=20, voffset=20, 
                                         css='.mpld3-tooltip{background-color: #fcc; padding: 15px}')
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip2)

# ---

mpld3.show()
```

Comment: it only shows how important is to create `minimal working code` which we can use to test solution. Put your code at the end of your question - it will be more readable, and more people will see it - so maybe someone else will help you.

Comment: Ignore my question works perfectly per my code as well, thanks!

Comment: Wondering, is there a way to display multiple ones of those graphs where i can hover over points in a single html page?

Comment: `PointHTMLTooltip` gets `scatter` as parameter and I think you may create many `PointHTMLTooltip` with different `scatter`

Comment: using `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)` you can create two separted plots using `s1 = ax1.scatter()` and `s2 = ax2.scatter()`. And later you can use `s1` and `s2` to create two `tooltips1`, `tooltips2` and add both to page. I see only one problem - both use the same `.mpld3-tooltip` in HTML so `css=...` will set the same color for both plots.

Comment: I added example with two plots.